# filtering negative values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, filter

I am trying to code a numpy function that shows the number of values that are less than 0 within an array. How would I be able to do that?

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([10,4,3,5,6,67,3,-12,5,-6,-7])
```

Expected Output:

```
3
```

Comment: You can get a boolean array satisfying your condition and call sum: `(array < 0).sum()`.

Answer (score 6):

Just compare the array against a value (i.e. less than zero for negative values), then call `sum` since, you only need the count.

```py
>>> array = np.array([10,4,3,5,6,67,3,-12,5,-6,-7])
>>> (array<0).sum()
3
```

And if you want those values instead of just count, then use the masking to get those values

```py
>>> array[array<0]
array([-12,  -6,  -7])
```

Comment: i never realized lists did this, is this just a numpy array thing?

Comment: Yeah, it's numpy

Answer (score 1):

you can print it with:

```
print(sum([i for i in array if i < 0]))
```

you can set it to a variable with:

```
lessThanZero = sum([i for i in array if i < 0])
```

did a benchmark (of sorts)

```
import datetime
import numpy
numpySum=0
forLoop=0
test = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
for k in range(1000):
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    for j in range(100):
        z = (test<5).sum()
    b = datetime.datetime.now() - a
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    for j in range(100):
        z = [i for i in test if i < 5]
    a = datetime.datetime.now() - a
    if b<a:numpySum+=1
    else: forLoop+=1
    
print(numpySum, forLoop)
```

output over 3 runs:

```
633 367
752 248
714 286
```

appears the numpy sum is faster :D

This was for an array of size 10. I tried again with size 1000, and the numpy sum answer won every time!

Comment: This will give the sum of negative values instead of the count.

Comment: This is not the way to work with numpy arrays. This will run in python time, but a native numpy approach will run in C time (which could be orders of magnitude faster)

Comment: I don't use numpy a lot, so I wanted to test it. Thank you @roganjosh that makes total sense. numpy clearly won.